# C# Why IEnumerable and IEnumerable.ToList() print their result is difference?

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I get the sequence number 0 ~ 2 with IEnumerable and when I print the result. The `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable.ToList()` result is difference.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var numbers = GetNumbers();
    Print(numbers); 
    /*  
    Return: 0
    Print: 0
    Return: 1
    Print: 1
    Return: 2
    Print: 2
    Return: 0
    Return: 1
    Return: 2
    Total: 3
    */
    
    Print(numbers.ToList());
    /*
    Return: 0
    Return: 1
    Return: 2
    Print: 0
    Print: 1
    Print: 2
    Total: 3    
    */
}

void Print(IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
    foreach(var number in numbers) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Print: {number}");
    }   
    Console.WriteLine($"Total: {numbers.Count()}");
}
 
IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{ 
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
        .Select(n =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Return: {n}");
            return n;
        });
}
```

Seems the pure IEnumerable the linq `Select` function  is call twice when execute the `IEnumerable.Count()`.

What happened to this?

Comment: The enumerable is enumerated multiple times (each time it is looped) and this is noticed via the side-effect in the *source* of the enumerable (Select). This can also be problematic in other cases, such as returning Guid.NewGuid values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `numbers.Count()`, you're enumerating the `IEnumerable` again. Because the IEnumerable is enumerated twice, the Return lines are each printed twice.

The list conversion enumerates the `IEnumerable` to build the list, but after that, only the resulting `List<int>` is used by `Print`. When  `.Count()` is called on the List, which just returns the built-in `Count` property of `List<int>` and doesn't enumerate anything.